# Where should I finish "A Dam Fine Rescue"?

Tags: borderlands-2

Are there any advantages (or disadvantages) to finishing "A Dam Fine Rescue"

> in the Bloodshot Ramparts by destroying W4R-D3N there,

as opposed to deliberately waiting for

> the barge to take them to Friendship Gulag

and finishing the mission there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there's no difference.
You still get [the same amount of exp and always 4 Eridium](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/A_Dam_Fine_Rescue).

The only difference is that a supplementary objective to "destroy loaders" will also arise after you kill W4R-D3N, so if you want to farm a bit more exp or weapons let the timer run out and save Roland from the second location.

By the way, this mission is "a dam **long** rescue", so I always prefer to save time and end it as soon as possible.